# AWS Lambda Destination not triggering EventBridge destination

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

I am using the Amazon Selling Partner API (SP-API) and am trying to set up a Pub/Sub like system for receiving customer orders etc.

The Notifications API in SP-API sends notifications of different types in 2 different ways depending on what event you are using. Some send directly to eventBridge and others are sent to SQS. https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/notifications-api-v1-use-case-guide#section-notification-workflows

I have correctly set up the notifications that are directly sent to eventBridge, but am struggling to work the SQS notifications. I want all notifications to be send to my own endpoint.

For the SQS model, I am receiving notifications in SQS, which is set as a trigger for a Lambda function (This part works). The destination for this function is set as another eventBridge (this is that part that doesn't work). This gives the architecture as:
`SQS => Lambda => eventBridge => my endpoint`

Why is lambda not triggering my eventBridge destination in order to send the notifications?

**Execution Role Policies:**

- Lambda

  1. AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  2. AmazonSQSFullAccess
  3. AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess
  4. AWSLambda_FullAccess
- EventBridge

  1. Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Api_Destination
  2. AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess
  3. AWSLambda_FullAccess

**EventBridge Event Pattern:**

`{"source": ["aws.lambda"]}`

**Execution Role Trusted Entities:**

- EventBridge Role
  `"Service": ["events.amazonaws.com", "lambda.amazonaws.com", "sqs.amazonaws.com"]`
- Lambda Role
  `"Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com", "events.amazonaws.com", "sqs.amazonaws.com"]`

**Lambda Code:**

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   console.log("Received event: ", event);
   context.callbackWaitForEmptyEventLoop = false
   callback(null, event);
   return {
      statusCode: 200,
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check if your lambda function has been configured properly for asynchronous execution ?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

In order to use lambda destination feature, the lambda function need to be configured properly for asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to share the access policy for SQS que? I have setup the SQS que to receive notifications but nothing is landing in my SQS que, the subscription and destination is setup, I am suspecting that there is an issue with the access, it would be very helpful is you could share the access policy  format that is working for your SQS que.

This is what I am using:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1652298563852",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1652298557402",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::82382xxxx:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:SetQueueAttributes"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:823829xxxx:SDNotificationsQueue1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe look into using 'GetQueueAttributes' instead of set for adding items to the SQS queue